# Разрешить доступ к ipv6-порту через роутер с OpenWrt

Tags: роутер, firewall, ipv6, openwrt, tp-link

Перепрошил роутер на OpenWrt и заработал ipv6.

Как оказалось, роутер содержит firewall, который блокирует доступ к портам через ipv6 из внешней сети, хотя и разрешает из домашней.

Для ipv4 я настроил статический ip для компьютера и в разделе проброс портов настроил проброс интересующего порта. А как то же самое сделать для ipv6? Обращаю внимание, что я хочу сделать доступным только один порт, а не все.

Крайне желательно настроить через веб-интерфейс luci.

Comment: модель роутера какая?

Comment: @eri, tp-link wr842nd ru второй версии.

Comment: можешь же раздать ip6 в локалку без ната. его ж обычно пачками выделяют

Comment: @eri, там и нет NAT'а - внешний и внутренний ip-адреса совпадают. Есть именно встроенный в прошивку роутера firewall, который обращения из внешней сети зарезает. Вопрос, как настроить этот firewall, чтобы он пропускал обращения на конкретные порты конкретных устройств. Полностью отключать всё-таки не хотелось бы.